# How to add .egg file library of python for eclipse on mac

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, m2crypto

I am using mac osx 10.8.2 and python 2.7 on eclipse IDE.I want to add M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg library on eclipse in eclipse --> preferences-->Interpreter Python. As in my code, I am importing `import M2Crypto` statement. I tried with `ALZip` and fileviewer to extract it, but it is showing an error as `[M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg] is a format that is not supported`. So, how I will use this library in my code on eclipse.

Comment: instead of decreasing reputation, you should correct the question format if any, and reply the answer

Comment: I don't use Eclipse myself, but isn't there in Project/Preference/Python(?) some tab for additional libraries. I believe it should be able to import EGG/ZIP directly.